# I have a curl command I want to convert to groovy native connection

Tags: json, http, curl, groovy, rest

I have been working on converting the curl command to native groovy connection.The curl command provided by the vendor is as follows:
curl -u admin:admin -F info=@issueFields.json -F result=@results.json http://yourserver/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/multipart

I have already created the info and result files as pretty json output. The result file I have verified works in the system by importing manually.

Here is my code thus far

```
    String strBaseURL = 'https://jstg.XXXXXXX.com/'
    String strUserName = 'myuser'
    //TODO set password before testing
    String strUserPwd = 'fakepassword'
    String strInfoFile = 'C:\\temp\\JSON\\executionInfo_Pretty.json'
    String strExecResultsFile = 'C:\\temp\\JSON\\execResults_pretty.json'
    String strAPIPath = 'rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/multipart'
    String strAuthType = 'Basic'
    
    String strMethodDetails
    Map mapMethodResults = [:]
    String authString = "${strUserName}:${strUserPwd}".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
    URL url = new URL ("${strBaseURL}${strAPIPath}")
    HttpURLConnection conXray = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()
    conXray.addRequestProperty('Authorization', strAuthType + ' ' + authString)
    conXray.addRequestProperty('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    conXray.setRequestMethod("POST")
    conXray.setConnectTimeout(1000)
    conXray.setDoOutput(true)
```

I am receiving a 415 error so I know I am connecting. I have tried various ways to attempt adding the two file one for info and one for result. Any suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to use native groovy commands only if possible.

Thank you
PGK

Comment: 415 = unsupported mediatype. -F in curl produces multipart content type. Add -v to curl to see all headers and how body should look like.

Comment: Hi daggett, thank you for responding. I see where I need to add the  -F info=@issueFields.json -F result=@results.json if I was using curl, but I want to replace curl with the native groovy calls. Any suggestion on how to accomplist this?

Comment: again: add `-v` option to curl command. then it will show you all the details how you should send http headers and body. note: it's not simple to build multipart content type in plain groovy/java. however it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

nothing to do.. so, here is the code to send multipart with plain groovy.

warning: no checks, not suitable for large files

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

def writeMultipart(w, String boundary,List data){
    data.each{v->
        // eval some defaults
        if(v.value instanceof File && !v.filename)v.filename=v.value.getName()
        if(v.filename && !v.contentType)v.contentType=Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(v.filename))
        // write
        w << '--' << boundary << '\r\n'
        w << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"${v.name}\"" << (v.filename ? "; filename=\"${v.filename}\"" : "") << '\r\n'
        if(v.contentType) w << "Content-Type: " << v.contentType << '\r\n'
        w << "Content-transfer-encoding: base64" << '\r\n'
        w << '\r\n'
        w << v.value.bytes.encodeBase64() << '\r\n'
    }
    w << '--' << boundary << '--' << '\r\n' //end of multipart
}

URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/post")
String user = 'myuser'
String pass = 'fakepassword'
String auth = "Basic " + "${user}:${pass}".bytes.encodeBase64()
String boundary = '#'*20 + Long.toHexString(UUID.randomUUID().mostSignificantBits)
def data = [
    [name: 'info',   value: new File('1.txt')],
    [name: 'result', value: new File('2.bin')],
    [name: 'hello',  value: 'world!'],
]


HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()
conn.addRequestProperty('Authorization', auth)
conn.addRequestProperty('Content-Type', "multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundary}")
conn.setRequestMethod("POST")
conn.setDoOutput(true)
conn.getOutputStream().withWriter{ w-> writeMultipart(w, boundary, data) }
//writeMultipart(System.out, boundary, data)
def code = conn.getResponseCode()
def resp = null
try{
    resp = conn.inputStream.text
}catch(e){
    resp = conn.errorStream?.text
}

println """
code = $code
response = $resp
"""
```

Comment: Hi Daggett, thank you for working on this solution. I am not sure what I have missed but I am getting an error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: resources.common.JiraXrayIntegration$_XrayPostExecResults_closure1.writeMultipart() is applicable for argument types: (OutputStreamWriter, String, ArrayList) values: [java.io.OutputStreamWriter@6408be5, ####################4c886814b8374b52, ...]

Comment: Here is the call: conXray.getOutputStream().withWriter{ w-> writeMultipart(w, boundary, data) }      I copied the code you gave for the writer but it does not seem to go into the code.

Comment: the code above is working in a standard groovy console. according to error message you are running inside closure. you have to declare function outside the closure or other option - convert writeMultipart declaration to a closure: `def writeMultipart = {w, String boundary,List data -> ...function body... }`